# Importing custom post types using WordPress Importer, how to check for meta field values

Tags: import

I have a custom post type that takes only the title field. Associated with it I have a custom meta field that takes a URL.

I am using the WordPress Importer plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/) to import posts from another site into this one, and by default WP checks whether there is the same post type and whether there are any same titles, in which case it skips over that record.

Now I not only want to check for title but also for that URL meta field, because in this case it is more of a unique identifier, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to modify these lines in the *WordPress-Importer* plugin:

```
$post_exists = post_exists( $post['post_title'], '', $post['post_date'] );
if ( $post_exists && get_post_type( $post_exists ) == $post['post_type'] ) {
```

to add some *post meta* checks.

I don't see any hooks inside the function `post_exists()` that we could use.

### Remark:

I don't recommend editing plugin files, but if this is a one time import and you can't find any other solution, then you might give it a try.

### Idea:

So you could try to replace the above lines with the following snippet:

```
$post_exists = post_exists( $post['post_title'], '', $post['post_date'] );

//
// if the post exists, let's check if it has the right post meta stuff
//
$my_meta_key = 'url'; // Edit this to your needs
$meta_exists = FALSE;

if ( $post_exists > 0 && isset( $post['postmeta'] ) ) 
{
    foreach( $post['postmeta'] as $meta ) 
    {
        if ( $my_meta_key === $meta['key'] ) 
        {
            if( $meta['value'] === get_post_meta( $post_exists, $my_meta_key, TRUE ) )
                $meta_exists = TRUE;

            break;
        }
    }
}

if ( $post_exists && $meta_exists && get_post_type( $post_exists ) == $post['post_type'] ) 
{
   ...
```

where you must modify the `$my_meta_key` to your needs.

This idea is untested so remember to take a **backup** before testing.

Comment: The situation is not a one time thing. I have a plugin and want users to use this import facility within this plugin.